# Capturing Apex Dataloader soap requests in Fiddler

Tags: soap, salesforce, fiddler, interception

I want to monitor the Apex DataLoader SOAP requests via Fiddler and as a first step I have imported the Fiddler Certificate in to "cacerts" in jre/security location in both DataLoader installation and JDK installation paths. Now I am able to perform import and export operations from Dataloader via Fiddler, but I see only Connect (Grayed out Tunnel) traffic. How to see the complete SOAP request and response?

Answer (score 1):

Solved :-). Exported the Fiddler cert from Personal Certificate Store ([see-here](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsclientcerts.asp)) then placed it at %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Fiddler2 location and restarted Fiddler. I can now see the full soap requests and responses. BTW the OS is Windows7, DataLoader version is 25.0.0 and Fiddler-2.4.10.

Comment: Would you be able to provide the exact step by step instructions you took to do this? I'm in great need of doing these but I'm not sure how to install the Fiddler Certificate in to the cacerts folder.

Comment: Hi, these are the steps that I've followed1- 
6- Once in Portecle, click on File > Open Keystore File and search for the "cacerts" file in Desktop.
7- Double click and when prompted for a password, type in "changeit" (without the quotes) and click Ok
8- Click Tools > Import Trusted Certificate
9- Find the "FiddlerRoot.cert" file from step 1 and click Import
10- Click Ok on the next two prompts and then Yes
11- Change the Alias name to FiddlerCert (or any other name you want) and click Ok
12- Click the Save icon
13- Take the "cacerts" file and paste it on the file path. This is not working